# Wrapping localStorage in a angular2 service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, local-storage

Is it wise to wrap the local storage in a service in angular2. Are there any arguments why this should be done like that. Obviously it is much neater. Calling the service as a dependency injection on a component. I don't see any other "pros" on that.

For example (local storage in a service)

```
setHost(value: string) {
    localStorage.setItem(STATIC_VARIABLE_KEY, value);
  }

  getHost(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem(STATIC_VARIABLE_KEY);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the main reason why it is good idea is that there are still browsers, that does not support `localStorage` when in private mode, and by using this layer of abstraction, you can simply replace `localStorage` with `cookie`, when it's not available.

For example even MacOS safari in incognito mode was not supporting it until latest High Sierra release. Mobile Safari has this problem also. (I think it's still there on iOS 11, not sure tho.)

But I would suggest using some ready made solution, instead of doing it from scratch. Take a look at this module:

https://github.com/phenomnomnominal/angular-2-local-storage

Another reason for doing this could be compatibility with server side rendering (via angular/universal) as `localStorage` is not available on server side at all.